# What happens when an aircraft activates reverse thrust mid flight?

Tags: thrust-reverser

I know that airplanes have several mechanisms in place to prevent such an occurrence from taking place, but am still curious as to what would happen if the reverse thrust activates mid flight.

Comment: On the CRJs, if a reverser becomes unstowed, there is either a mechanical device to drive the thrust lever to idle (on CRJ200, a big spring jack on the engine forces the lever back, which means you never hook your thumbs under the thrust lever handles, just use the heel of your hand to push, lest it dislocates your thumb if it ever is released), or on a FADEC airplane the computer puts the engine to idle.  I can imagine that if this happens at cruise thrust, the reverse may not dissipate fast enough to save you.

Comment: The pilot would need to turn and look behind while backing up.